# Let's Encrypt on different port

Tags: ubuntu, lets-encrypt

I am currently running two virtual machines, and each one (Ubuntu 18.04) is running an Apache web server. The physical host is reachable with DDNS, so I can access the first virtual machine’s web server via port 80 by entering the DDNS in the web browser. I can access the second virtual machine’s web server using port 81. 
I wanted to use Let’s Encrypt for HTTPS on both web servers. It works fine with the first virtual machine, but it doesn’t work on the second virtual machine on port 81.
I considered using two DDNS on my home router, but it’s not possible to set two in my router settings.

So what are my options? Thanks in advance!